# Create all possible combinations of

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like, in PostgreSQL, to create all possible combinations of values from 3 different tables put together as unique strings separated with underscore _.

Ex.:

```
table car_type
column 'type' contains: diesel, gasoline, electric

table car_color
column 'color' contains: black, blue, red

table car_stereo
column 'checked' contains: true, false
```

I would like a view which contained all values:

```
diesel_black_true
diesel_blue_true
diesel_red_true
diesel_black_false
diesel_blue_false
diesel_red_false
gasoline_black_true
gasoline_red_true
...
```

Hope it makes sense, is it possible in a generic and dynamic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Cross Join` the tables to get all the combinations

```
Select t.type||'_'||c.color||'_'||s.checked
From car_type t
Cross join car_color c
Cross join car_stereo s;
```